# Interpret `--` like `cargo run` using clap

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, clap

In Rust, how can I implement argument parsing like what cargo does here?

```
cargo run -v -- -w
```

`-v` is a cargo option, but `-w` becomes an option on the executable cargo builds.

I would like my software to do the same thing.  I.e. my user provides options to my executable *before* `--`, but then any arguments *after* `--` forward to a different executable that my executable invokes.

Is this possible using clap?

Answer (score 3):

It should work out of the box:

```
use clap::*;

fn main() {
    let cmd = Command::new ("prog")
        .arg (Arg::new ("verbose")
              .short ('v'))
        .arg (Arg::new("extra")
              .num_args (0..));
    
    let m = cmd.get_matches_from(vec![ "prog", "-v", "1", "--", "-w" ]);
    println!("verbose: {}", m.get_one::<String>("verbose").unwrap());
    println!("extra: {:?}", m.get_many::<String>("extra").unwrap().collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=893a4701ae7d661992a1634e8a4e550f)

Or with the `derive` API:

```
use clap::Parser;

#[derive (Parser, Debug)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(short, long)]
    verbose: bool,
    extra: Vec<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse_from(vec![ "prog", "-v", "--", "-w" ]);
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=50b9df963abb61c00a0d44cf6ab7f683)

If you want the `--` to be mandatory even if the extra arguments don't start with `-`, you need to use [`last`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.last) for your catch-all argument:

```
.arg (Arg::new("extra")
      .num_args (0..)
      .last(true)
```

or

```
#[derive (Parser, Debug)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(short, long)]
    verbose: bool,
    #[arg(last = true)]
    extra: Vec<String>,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using the [`Arg::raw()`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.raw) method.

Using the derive syntax:

```rust
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(raw = true)]
    cmd: Vec<String>,
}
```